# Getting Null Pointer Exception when try to fetch the query result in springboot

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get all the data from my SQL table. I am trying to use @Query in the repository.

When I try to get these within my controller class as shown below using API I am getting it fine and it give me the correct value.

However issue arises when I am trying to use the same value within my service class it is showing me null .However I need to use these values in service class for further purposes but I am unable to use it because of this error.

Below is my repository:

```java
public interface DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<DemoStudentData, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT SUM(dt.demo_marks) FROM DemoStudentData dt")
    Double totalMarks();

}
```

here is the API which is giving me correct value when I try to test.(I only used it to check if I get correct value in GET request).

```java
@GetMapping(value="/totalMarks", produces = "application/json")
     public double getTotalMarks(){


     return demoRepository.totalMarks();
        }
```

Below is my service class where I need to get the value.

```java
   @Service
   public class SampleMarksValues {


    @Autowired
    private DemoRepository demoRepository;

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void useTotalMarks(DemoStudentData demo) {
        Double Marks = demoRepository.totalMarks(); //showing null here.

        demo.setTotal_Marks(Marks);

    }

}
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting such an issue. Can anyone help me with this?.

Comment: might be that demoRepository is null. might be the method call throws the exception. have you debugged your code?

Comment: Where do you use and how do you instantiate the class `SampleMarksValues`?

Comment: You are probably missing @Repository annotation in your repository class that's why spring does not create bean

Comment: @RafałSokalski It's a Spring Data interface, `@Repository` is not necessary on those.

Comment: @Stultuske. how can i verify if demoRepository is null or not. If it is null then why i am getting the correct value when i call that value in GET API

Comment: @Kumar_Maddy because it is instantiated in one class/flow, doesn't mean it is in another. you can add a print statement, you can debug your code, there are several ways, all of which you should have known about before trying to write more 'complex' code

Comment: @Stultuske i tried using print statement in service class method and i was getting null. I want to know how can i get rid of it. Is there any way to instaniate it within service class??

Comment: make sure that service class is itself instantiated in the Spring context, or the Autowired won't take

Comment: What is showing null? demoRepository or demoRepository.totalMarks() ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski i also checked demorepository in print statement.```            System.out.println("total marks "+demoRepository)```
 it is also showing null. here is output ```total marks null```

Comment: @Stultuske can you please provide any reference for instantiating service class in Spring??

Comment: by Autowiring it, just like you try with your repository, but you have to autowire the entire flow

Comment: @Stultuske entire flow??

Comment: @Stultuske i used @autowire annotaion within controller class  to instaniate it. still its not working.  What am i missing here now?? ```
@Autowired
private SampleMarksValues sampleMarksValues;```

Comment: that is not what I was talking about. You should read up on it works. If you add @Autowired on that variable, for instance, but instantiate the Controller by " = new Controller", that Autowired won't do anything

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks mate. The issue is resolved now. I have been able to figure out the autowirig and instanitaing thing. As i instantiated using autowiring and called the method within controllr, it worked